# Is it possible to create an RDD in sbt console?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm working in SBT console and have imported the following

```
scala> import org.apache.spark._
scala> val sc = new SparkContext("local", "shell")
scala> import org.apache.spark.rdd._
```

I would like to make an `RDD[Myclass]` in the console. Is that possible?

```
scala> case class MyClass(foobar: String, something: String)
```

The reason I want to do this is to play around with RDD and create sample data that I can test with. Rather than reading a textFile or reading huge data from HDFS or S3

Comment: This is the spark shell, not the "sbt console"

Comment: did you try `parallelize`, e.g. `sc.parallelize(List(MyClass("a", "b"), MyClass("c", "d")))`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have a project with build.sbt. In this project I execute `sbt console` and get to this shell

Comment: You should probably use `spark-shell`. You can pass `-i` to load a scala file. SBT is a build tool, I don't think you can start a spark context from its console

Comment: ah ok. So from spark-shell I can do everything I can from "sbt console" + all spark stuff but from "sbt-console" I cant do all of spark stuff.

Comment: @cricket_007, one can use the Spark API to create a context from the SBT console. This is no different than having a stand-alone Scala program establishing a Spark context. It's documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) under _Self-Contained Applications_.

Comment: @HristoIliev I have never seen `sbt console`, just `sbt package` followed by `spark-submit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sc.parallelize` and give that a `List` of your objects.